# How to use one formula in a cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I'm forecasting multiple items monthly over ten years.  There are several products that will be introduced during future months while others are simultaneously phased out. I have formulas for the phase-out period of 12 months, but the specific month the process will begin is not known yet.

Is there a way to use one formula in a cell given a FALSE condition and the same formula with one more factor added (an additional multiplier) when there is a TRUE condition?  I would like to use a trigger date to 'switch' the formulas from the trigger month twelve months forward, then revert automatically to the original formula after 12 months where the modified equation was operable.

It would be kind of like 'conditional formatting' but rather than formatting it would be 'conditional formulating.' Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Use the [IF function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IF-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2).

```
=IF(logical_test, value_if_true, [value_if_false])
```

Comment: Thanks Steven - I do know that route but the formulas are already in place so this would be a 'brute force' approach.  I wonder if there is an easier way?

Comment: @MichaelGuilbault In what way is this brute force? This seems to be exactly what you asked for. Could you please clarify what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to do this would be to use the 'IF' function in conjunction with your formulas. You will just need to decide what constitutes 'True' and 'False'. Try something like:

```
=IF(B33=G11,SUM(B20),SUM(C20))
```

Where 'B33=G11' constitutes it being 'True' or 'False'. If it was 'True' the function would use the 'SUM(B20). If it was 'False' the function would use 'SUM(C20)

Comment: Thanks Android - I was hoping to do it without using logicals like IF,OR,AND,NO

Comment: You can always reference your formula cell. That way it would stay dynamic.

Comment: You know - the referencing the formula idea might work....THX